# Como mostrar y ocultar según seleccione algo de una determinada lista

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

una ayuda por favor quisiera mostrar una lista dentro de otra lista segun la opciones que  seleccione algo, al seleccionar de la lista esta muestre sus opciones que tiene y así sucesivamente. 
Espero hacerme entender e buscado en internet y no logro funcionar.

Seria de la sgte forma.

[image: lista de un servicio determinado]

al seleccionar algo de la lista que muestre otra lista según el servicio que escogí

Espero ser claro en el codigo tengo lo siguiente.

```js
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
  function MostrarServicio(value)
    {
        if (value == '0029')
            document.getElementById("servicio").style.display = '';
        else
            document.getElementById("servicio").style.display = 'none';
```

```html
 `<label class="weight-600">CLIENTE:</label>
    <select class="custom-select form-control" name="cod_cliente">
         <?
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                   echo "<option value='$row[0]' onclick=MostrarServicio'(this.value)'>
     $row[1] ";
    mysql_close($link);
          ?>

<!--Servio Renta Dig-->
<div id="servicio" style="display: none;">
  <td>Servicio: </td>
  <td>
        <select class="custom-select form-control" name="servicio">
          <option value="1">Pagos</option>
            <option value="2">Actualizaciones</option>
          <option value="3">Gastos Funerales</option>
          <option value="4">RD y GF</option>
        </select>
  </td>
</div> `
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar estoy ocupando el boostrap ese codigo me funciona solamente en mozila pero no en otros navegadores. es codigo antiguo y tengo que actualizarlo.
GRacias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo que tienes que hacer es generar un listener al evento change del select que contiene las categorías "padres" y en ese evento tiene que hacer el cmabio de lo que quieres mostrar dependendiendo del valor seleccionado.
Te dejo un ejemplo.
Saludos.

```js
const rubros = document.getElementById('rubros');

    function ocultarTodosLosSubrubros() {
      document.getElementById(`subrubros-1`).style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById(`subrubros-2`).style.display = 'none';
    }

    rubros.addEventListener('change', () => {
      ocultarTodosLosSubrubros();
      if (rubros.value > -1) {
        document.getElementById(`subrubros-${rubros.value}`).style.display = 'block';
      }
    });

    ocultarTodosLosSubrubros();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>


<div>
    <select name="rubros" id="rubros">
        <option value="-1">Seleccionar</option>
        <option value="1">Elemento 1</option>
        <option value="2">Elemento 2</option>
    </select>
    <h2 id="subrubros-1">SUBRUBROS 1</h2>
    <h2 id="subrubros-2">SUBRUBROS 2</h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me funciono..  el javascritp estaba peleando.